# new to argParse, not sure where my error is

Tags: python, argparse

I am completely new to Python, just started today and getting to grips with Python. Running it in Visual Studio btw.

Came across the `import argParse` and this is where things got a bit confusing for me. 
I have some code I'm trying to get to work but it won't and I am quite clueless. 
I'm getting an error on the code `args = parser.parse_args()` and I have no idea why either. Code is below

```
import math
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='calculate')
parser.add_argument('radius', type=int, help="radius plzz")
parser.add_argument('height', type=int, help="height plzz")
args = parser.parse_args()


def cylinder_volume(radius, height):
    vol = (math.pi) * (radius ** 2) * height
    return vol

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(cylinder_volume(args.radius, args.height))
```

I do have an idea of what's going on in this code but I don't know why it won't run as expected? 
Maybe because I'm using Visual Studio? Maybe I need to import something else..

I have an image of the error!
[image]

Comment: Please show your error, it's will be helpful.

Comment: @FlorianBernard, I've added one, thanks for having a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`args = parser.parse_args()` parses the command line arguments (accessible as the `sys.argv` list) and makes the first argument `args.radius` and the second argument `args.height`, per the calls to the `add_argument` method. So all you need to do is to run the script from the command line with two integer arguments, e.g.:

```
script_name.py 123 456
```

or to test it in an IDE such as Visual Studio, you can pass a list of arguments to `parse_args` instead:

```
args = parser.parse_args(['123', '456'])
```

which outputs:

```
21673294.79680895
```

Comment: Adding the parser_args(['123', '456']) sorted it out for me. Quick question, how can I run my script the other way you pointed out, the 'script_name.py 123 456'?

Comment: You would have to run something like `python PythonApplication1CommandLine.py 123 456` in the command line (in a `cmd.exe` or PowerShell session) in the directory where the script is located.

Comment: Thank you! You've been very helpful

Answer (score 0):

you can add 'dest=(str)' to send the argument as an attribute of args.

```
parser.add_argument(
          'radius',
          type=int,
          help="radius plzz",
          dest='radius'
         )
parser.add_argument(
                'height',
                type=int,
                help="height plzz",
                dest='height'
               )
```

Then you can call the arguments as you did in:

```
print(cylinder_volume(args.radius, args.height))
```